# Method [all] does not exist. laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

это контроллер:

```
class Asa extends Controller {


public function index()
{
    $model  = Asa::all();
    return View('asa');
}
}
```

а это модель:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Asa extends Model {

    //

}
```

а это ошибка:

> Method [all] does not exist.

как её исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Asa extends Controller {
```

есть практика наименований, которая рекомендует нам такое наименование контроллеров

```
class AsaController extends Controller {
```

убедитесь что метод `all()` у класса `Asa` или его родителей существует

Answer (score 0):

Так как контроллер и модель имеют одинаковые имена, видимо обращение идёт не к модели Asa, а к контроллеру Asa. Попробуйте использовать полное имя типа App\models\Asa или какой путь у вас.

Comment: не помог.......